# timeit ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable

Tags: python, callable, timeit

I played with `timeit` in Python, got a weird problem.

I define a simple function `add`.  `timeit` works when I pass `add` two string parameters. But it raises `ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable` when I pass `add` two `int` parameters.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def add(x,y):
...     return x + y
... 


>>> a = '1'
>>> b = '2'
>>> timeit.timeit(add(a,b))
0.01355926995165646


>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> timeit.timeit(add(a,b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/timeit.py", line 233, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/timeit.py", line 130, in __init__
    raise ValueError("stmt is neither a string nor callable")
ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable
```

Why does the parameter type matter at all here?

Comment: *Why wouldn't the type of the object matter?*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your mistake is to assume that Python passes the expression `add(a, b)` to `timeit()`. That's not the case, `add(a, b)` is not a string, it is an expression so Python instead *executes* `add(a, b)` and the *result* of that call is passed to the `timeit()` call.

So for `add('1', '2')` the result is `'12'`, a string. Passing a string to `timeit()` is fine. But `add(1, 2)` is `3`, an integer. `timeit(3)` gives you an exception. Not that timing `'12'` is all that interesting, of course, but that is a valid Python expression producing the integer value 12:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def add(x, y):
...     return x + y
...
>>> a = '1'
>>> b = '2'
>>> add(a, b)
'12'
>>> timeit.timeit('12')
0.009553937998134643
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> add(a, b)
3
>>> timeit.timeit(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/timeit.py", line 232, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "/.../lib/python3.7/timeit.py", line 128, in __init__
    raise ValueError("stmt is neither a string nor callable")
ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable
```

That's all perfectly normal; otherwise, how could you ever pass the result of a function to another function directly? `timeit.timeit()` is *just another Python function*, nothing so special that it'll disable the normal evaluation of expressions.

What you want is to pass a *string with the expression* to `timeit()`. `timeit()` doesn't have access to your `add()` function, or `a` or `b`, so you need to give it access with the second argument, the setup string. You can use `from __main__ import add, a, b` to import the `add` function object:

```
timeit.timeit('add(a, b)', 'from __main__ import add, a, b')
```

Now you get more meaningful results:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def add(x, y):
...     return x + y
...
>>> a = '1'
>>> b = '2'
>>> timeit.timeit('add(a, b)', 'from __main__ import add, a, b')
0.16069997000158764
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> timeit.timeit('add(a, b)', 'from __main__ import add, a, b')
0.10841095799696632
```

So adding integers is faster than adding strings. You probably want to try this with different sizes of integers and strings, but adding integers will remain the faster result.

Answer (score 20):

With the string version add returns a string, which timeit can evaluate. So "12" is a valid python expression while 3 is not.

```
timeit.timeit("12") # works
timeit.timeit(3) # does not
```

The best way to use timeit, is to wrap the function you want to test with a lambda:

```
timeit.timeit(lambda: add(1,2))
```

This is much more elegant and less error prone than dealing with string.

*Note that the lambda introduces some slight overhead to each call. If your function does anything remotely complex this will be negligible, but for very simple snippets (like "a+b") the overhead will have a significant impact.*

Comment: I've tested your version and compare it with the one with strings and using lambda adds some overhead. It took almost 50% more time compared with the regular string version.: timeit.timeit(stmt='add(2,3)', setup='from __main__ import add') vs timeit.timeit(lambda: add(2, 3))

Comment: For testing one method call, it could easily add a significant amount of time. It was my impression that you should benchmark a method by calling it many times. That will make the added time negligible.

Comment: a function cannot get much simpler than this - as long as the code you are testing is a normal function one additional method call can be neglected.
I'll add this information to the answer

Answer (score 7):

> my question is why the parameter type matters here?

Function arguments are fully evaluated before the function is called.  That means when you do:

```
timeit.timeit(add(a,b))
```

Then `add(a,b)` has already been computed before `timeit` is used.  So, it has nothing to time.

The reason `timeit.timeit(add(a,b))` "works" when a and b are numeric strings is just a silly one: it's timing the evaluation of `'12'`. The result of calling `add('1', '2')` happens to be a valid string of Python code here.  `timeit` compiles it and assumes you wanted to time the evaluation of the literal integer 12.

Comment: thanks for  your generous answer! Does it mean passing add('1', '2') is equivalent to the following code?

timeit.timeit("add(1,2)","from __main__ import add")

Comment: How should the OP modify the code so that the time for evaluating the sum of integers can be measured?

Comment: @liangli Not exactly. But that is one correct way to time the actual execution of `add` using integer arguments.

Comment: @liangli: no, it is the *return value* of `add()` that is passed to `timeit`. `add('1', '2')` returns the string `'12'`, so it is the equivalent of `timeit('12')`.

Comment: since add(a,b) passed is not a string, i am curious what happens under the hood. say, why does timeit not take add(1,2) as a valid string of python code?

Comment: @liangli: `add(1, 2)` is **not a string**, it is an expression that returns a result.

Answer (score 1):

another way of solving the type "problem" is by passing the result of the function as a string!

```
timeit.timeit('%s'%(add(1,2)))
or
timeit.timeit(f'{add(1,2)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old topic, but I've found similar way using `functools`, when you want to check single function and pass its parameters not using strings or lambdas:

```py
import timeit
import functools

def add(x,y):
    return x + y

a = 1
b = 2

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(add, a, b))
print(t.timeit(10))
```

Output:

```
4.565001290757209e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me, great!
used datetime before, but this way is far more comfortable!

Comment: "Me too" answers are not encouraged unless you add information to the other answers.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31450172)